# Find the eigenvectors of this sine/cosine matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have the following matrix
 $$
\begin{pmatrix}
cos\phi & -sin\phi \\
sin\phi & cos\phi &
\end{pmatrix}
\in \mathbb C^{2 \times 2}, \phi\in \mathbb R$$

and I am trying to find eigenvalues and eigenvectors of this function. In case $\phi$ is a multiple of $\pi$, it is trivial, since I end up with an identity function (or the negative version). But in the other case, I am having troubles. I know that I can compute the roots of the characteristic polynomial to find eigenvalues. In this case, I end up with: $$x_{1,2} = cos\phi \pm \sqrt{cos^2\phi-1}$$ 
So far so good. Then I went on to find the subspace of eigenvectors, by finding $ker(f-x*id_V)$. Chosing one of the eigenvectors I end up with a system of linear equations:
$$\sqrt{cos^2\phi-1} * x_1 - sin\phi  * x_2 = 0$$
$$sin\phi*x_1+\sqrt{cos^2\phi-1} * x_2 = 0$$ 
Is this the right way of doing it? If so, how to I correctly solve this homogenous system? I cant seem to solve it via row operations.

Comment: @uniquesolution I am working with complex numbers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you can rewrite that eigenvalue as

$$
\newcommand{\ii}{\mathbf i}
\cos (\varphi) \pm \ii \sin \varphi
$$
The corresponding eigenvector (for the positive choice) is $\begin{bmatrix} \ii \\ 1\end{bmatrix}$.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to bring some supplementary understanding.

In fact, this matrix, say $R_{\theta}$, is very classical: in $\mathbb{R^2}$,

$$\tag{1} V \to R_{\theta}V$$

is the rotation by angle $\theta$.

Thus, it does not come as a surprise that it is impossible to have $R_{\theta}V=\lambda V$ with $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$, i.e., $R_{\theta}V$ proportional to $V$, unless angle $\theta$ is $k\pi$ $k \in \mathbb{Z}.$ Thus, we can only await complex eigenvalues.

Nevertheless $e^{i \theta}$, in particular, is the most natural (eigen)value that can be associated with this matrix. Here is why:

In fact, in $\mathbb{R^2}$ assimilated to $\mathbb{C}$, the rotation around the origin with angle $\theta$ can be written under the complex form

$$\tag{2}z \to e^{i \theta}z$$

The parallel of (2) with (1) is clear...